# Mechanize not dealing with cookies like a browser does

Tags: html, perl, cookies, mechanize

I have the following code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$url = "http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E";
$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
$content = $mech->content();
while ($content =~ m/<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="(\d+); URL=(.+?)">/) {
    $refresh = $1;
    $link = $2;
    sleep $refresh;
    $mech->get($link);
    $content = $mech->content();
}
$mech->save_content("output.txt");
```

When I put the URL assigned to `$url` in a browser the end result is the downloading of a `PDF` file, but when I run the above code I end up with a different file.  I think that maybe `Mechanize` is not able to handle cookies properly.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E you first get a redirect to `https`.

Then you get a page with a `META REFRESH`. This gives you a file in `/TMP`.

After getting https://daccess-ods.un.org/TMP/xxx.xxx.html and following the `META REFRESH` to https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/G15/263/87/PDF/G1526387.pdf?OpenElement it still does not download the document, but gives an error message.

The reason when you examine the headers from the browser is because the browser sets three cookies, and WWW::Mechanize only one:

- citrix_ns_id=xxx
- citrix_ns_id_.un.org_%2F_wat=xxx
- LtpaToken=xxx

So where does these cookies come from? Turns out that the TMP html has more than a META REFRESH. It also has this HTML:

```
<frameset ROWS="0,100%" framespacing="0" FrameBorder="0" Border="0">
  <frame name="footer" scrolling="no" noresize target="main" src="https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/prod/ods_mother.nsf?Login&Username=freeods2&Password=1234" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <frame name="main" src="" scrolling="auto" target="_top">
  <noframes>
  <body>
  <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
  </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
```

This url https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/prod/ods_mother.nsf?Login&Username=freeods2&Password=1234 does set these cookies.

```
Set-Cookie: LtpaToken=xxx; domain=.un.org; path=/
Set-Cookie: citrix_ns_id=xxx; Domain=.un.org; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: citrix_ns_id_.un.org_%2F_wat=xxx; Domain=.un.org; Path=/
```

So by changing your code to take this into account:

```
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = "http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
my $more = 1;
while ($more) {
    $more = 0;
    my $follow_link;
    my @links = $mech->links;
    foreach my $link (@links) {
        if ($link->tag eq 'meta') {
            $follow_link = $link;
        }
        if (($link->tag eq 'frame') && ($link->url)) {
            $mech->follow_link( url => $link->url );
            $mech->back;
        }
    }
    if ($follow_link) {
        $more = 1;
        $mech->follow_link( url => $follow_link->url );
    }
}
$mech->save_content("output.txt");
```

output.txt successfully includes the pdf.

```
$ file output.txt
output.txt: PDF document, version 1.5
```

Comment: You have obviously given a good answer which solves the problem.  But just one thing: you say that `mech->get($link)` will not work without a full URL.  That is not correct.  I am able to get relative links with `get`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't know why I thought that. I must have made another error. I will update the answer. You can use `->follow_link` or `->get` as you like. If you use `->get` you can send the WWW::Mechanize::Link object.

Answer (score 1):

I get a 404 when I enter that URL in a browser, but try this code to get more detailed debugging output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy qw( debug_ua );
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $url
    = "http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/GetOpen&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
debug_ua( $mech );

$mech->get( $url );
my $content = $mech->content();
while (
    $content =~ m/<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="(\d+); URL=(.+?)">/ )
{
    my $refresh = $1;
    my $link    = $2;
    sleep $refresh;
    $mech->get( $link );
    $content = $mech->content();
}
$mech->save_content( "output.txt" );
```

Comment: Sorry that's a typo. I've edited the question to correct the URL.

Comment: Did you try the script I posted?

Comment: Because I am not at work I tried running your code at home on a Windows machine and `LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy` doesn't appear to be available.  Did you try the corrected URL?

Comment: You'd just need to install that module. I tried with your updated URL.  Not sure what's going on.  It's not the cookies, since WWW::Mechanize creates a cookie jar by default.  I tried adding a different UserAgent string, but that doesn't fix it either.  If you try my suggestion, you'll at least see more debugging info which may help you a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding a cookie jar to the constructor, something along these lines

```
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(file => $cookie_file, autosave => 1, ignore_discard => 1);
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new('ssl_opts'=> {'SSL_verify_mode'=>'SSL_VERIFY_NONE'}, cookie_jar => $cookie_jar, autocheck => 0);
```

If you want to save the cookie and then load it later to retain your sessions do something like this:

```
$cookie_jar->save; 
#after the content call
```

To load the cookie:

```
$mech->cookie_jar->load($cookie_file);
#before the get function (but you may want a conditional statement to check if the cookie even exists
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

This is how I automated this in `VBA`:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Declare Sub SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal _
    hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As _
    Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer)


'~~> Constants for pressing left button of the mouse
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Long = &H2
'~~> Constants for Releasing left button of the mouse
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Long = &H4

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Sub GetFiles()

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

GetFileFromUrl "http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E"
GetFileFromUrl "http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/31&Lang=F"

End Sub



Sub GetFileFromUrl(url As String)



Dim pos As RECT

ie.Navigate url

ie.Visible = True

While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Sleep 7000

ie.ExecWB 4, 1, "c:\test.pdf"

Sleep 5000


SaveAsHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save As")

If SaveAsHwnd <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print "Found Save As window"
Else
    Debug.Print "Did not find Save As window"
End If

SaveButtonHwnd = FindWindowEx(SaveAsHwnd, ByVal 0&, "Button", "&Save")

If SaveButtonHwnd <> 0 Then

    Debug.Print "Found Save button"

    ' click button
    'res = SendMessage(SaveButtonHwnd, TCM_SETCURFOCUS, 1, ByVal 0&)
    'res = PostMessage(SaveButtonHwnd, BM_CLICK, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&)
    'res = SendMessage(SaveButtonHwnd, WM_COMMAND, 0&, 0&)

    GetWindowRect SaveButtonHwnd, pos

    '~~> Move the cursor to the specified screen coordinates.
    SetCursorPos (pos.Left - 10), (pos.Top - 10)
    '~~> Suspends the execution of the current thread for a specified interval.
    '~~> This give ample amount time for the API to position the cursor
    Sleep 100
    SetCursorPos pos.Left, pos.Top
    Sleep 100
    SetCursorPos (pos.Left + pos.Right) / 2, (pos.Top + pos.Bottom) / 2

    '~~> Set the size, position, and Z order of "File Download" Window
    SetWindowPos Ret, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
    Sleep 100

    '~~> Simulate mouse motion and click the button
    '~~> Simulate LEFT CLICK
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, (pos.Left + pos.Right) / 2, (pos.Top + pos.Bottom) / 2, 0, 0
    Sleep 700
    '~~> Simulate Release of LEFT CLICK
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (pos.Left + pos.Right) / 2, (pos.Top + pos.Bottom) / 2, 0, 0

Else

    Debug.Print "Did not find Save button"

End If


Sleep 5000


End Sub
```

Alternatively, the `UIAutomation` `COM` object can be used:

```
Sub GetFilesAutomation()

Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement

Dim SaveAsHwnd As LongPtr
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Set o = New CUIAutomation

ie.Navigate "http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E"

ie.Visible = True

Sleep 10000

ie.ExecWB 4, 1

Sleep 5000

SaveAsHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save As")

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal SaveAsHwnd)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke

End Sub
```